# Progress while filling jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I would like to give progress to the user while Jasper reports is filling a compile report.
Basically I would like to get progress while this is executing:

JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperReport rpt, Map params, JRDataSource src)

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: We are using AsynchronousFillHandle and AsynchronousFilllListener, in which the fill happens on a different thread. This allows us to show our own progress bar, with the ability to cancel. Unfortunately, the listener does not give real progress indication, just notifies on completion or error, so the progress-bar is an 'infinite' one.

Comment: We achieve this already, using the job framework in our RCP/SWT/JFace application. We also don't have real progress. Its weird because there is progress available when exporting to file. I wonder who easy it is to contribute to Jasper...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Jasper Reports version **4.6.0** You can use `FillListener`:

```
AsynchronousFillHandle handle = AsynchronousFillHandle.createHandle(jasperReport, params, dataSource);
handle.addFillListener(new FillListener() {

    @Override
    public void pageUpdated(JasperPrint jasperPrint, int pageIndex) {
        log.info("pageUpdated " + pageIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public void pageGenerated(JasperPrint jasperPrint, int pageIndex) {
        log.info("pageGenerated " + pageIndex);
    }
});
```

**NOTE**: to build 4.6.0 version get sources from svn and use ant:

```
svn co http://jasperforge.org/svn/repos/jasperreports (user/pass: anonymous)
cd jasperreports\trunk\jasperreports
ant jar
```

Comment: Now it is available as part of the jasperreports-4.7.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this components from PrimeFaces to show that the report is generating:

```
<p:ajaxStatus onstart="dlg.show();" onsuccess="dlg.hide();" />
        <p:dialog modal="true"  header="Creating Report" widgetVar="dlg" draggable="false" closable="false" >
            <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/ajaxloadingbar.gif" />
        </p:dialog>
```

I don't have any real way to determine the total time my reports will take to compile and fill, so I opted not to use an actual progress bar which sometimes fills before the report is complete.

Comment: I'm thinking that proper report generation progress has to still be implemented properly in jasper reports and exposed to clients.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not possible to monitor progress of filling jasper report (as of version 4.0.2)- `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller` doesn't offer any kind of progress notification.