# Progress while creating DynamicReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

We have a "soft" requirement to display some sort of progress while a long running DynamicReport is generated. We use the toPdf, to*** methods of generating a report.

I'm thinking I would like to spawn a thread to generate the output file, and somehow report to the user on its progress. I'm familiar with how to implement this with ajax etc....but I can't seem to find how to hook into a dynamicreport generation to accomplish this.

I did come across [Progress while filling jasper report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021135/progress-while-filling-jasper-report), but I can't seem to figure out how this might apply.