# ProgressBar in DynamicReports

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I am using `Jasper` with `DynamicReports` to generate lists. My reports can take some time in generating (*5 mins*), and I would like to add a progress bar (**OR** a label with the rows / pages created) while doing the method `toJasperPrint()`, which I believe, fills the report.

**My code**:

```
JasperReportBuilder report = report();
[code ....]
LoadingFrame.getInstance().lblProgress.setText("Remplissage du rapport...");

/** Génération du fichier **/
JRViewer jv = new JRViewer(report.toJasperPrint());
JFrame jf = new JFrame(someName);
[code....]
```

Comment: What is the question ? How to create a progress bar ? How to get the number of pages created ?

Comment: Hello Talha, I am asking how to get the progress out of the method toJasperPrint(), as I want to show the user its progress step by step (It doesn't matter if it's a progress bar or labels). I already have a progress bar for the whole report, but the step for the report.toJasperPrint() is unknown. It could take 5 seconds or 5mins.

Comment: see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021135/progress-while-filling-jasper-report

Comment: Yes I already saw this thread, but I was wondering how to do it using Dynamic Reports